# why does SELECT INTO OUTFILE give file exists error even though file does not exist?

Tags: mysql

The file definitely does not exist, but I am getting an error anyway.

I do:

```
$ rm /tmp/records_materialized_view.txt;
$ mysql ... 

> SELECT * FROM records_materialized_view INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/records_materialized_view.txt';

ERROR 1086 (HY000): File '/tmp/records_materialized_view.txt' already exists
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT INTO OUTFILE` writes results to a server file.

Are you checking for the file existence on server?

If you want to select into a local file on your client machine, just redirect `mysql` output:

```
mysql mydb < script.sql > /tmp/records_materialized_view.txt
```

Comment: ah, but wait! how do I get the equivalent of FIELDS TERMINATED, OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED, etc...?

Comment: If you can use a scripting language like Python, Ruby or Perl this is pretty easy to accomplish.

Comment: resolved by dumping the file on the remote host and fetching it through scp. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this answer when I had a similar issue.

I realized that `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` does not overwrite files, you have to clean them up yourself. So you will get this error the next time you write it. Not sure what is meant by in the above answer, that the files are written to a server file.

Also, `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` by default writes files relative to your db data directory. The default location i.e.

```
/var/lib/mysql/
```

So if you check your db data directory, you should find your files there. Use an absolute path to control exactly where you want the file to end up. This is exactly what I was after, hopefully it helps somebody. Cheers.